# Xdebug - no profile or trace output

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, trace

I'm at a bit of a loss trying to get profiling and tracing working with Xdebug (debugging works fine).  What's worse is that I have it working just fine on a different server/client setup, but I can't seem to see the difference that and this developer workstation using localhost.  Nothing is being output to xdebug.log, either.

Server: Ubuntu 10.04, PHP 5.3.2, Xdebug 2.2.1

php.ini:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_append = 1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/xdebug-profiles"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="xdebug-profile.%t.%p"

xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.trace_options = 1 
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.trace_format=2
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/www/xdebug-traces"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%t.%p"

xdebug.file_link_format="xdebug://%f@%l"
xdebug.remote_log="/var/www/xdebug.log"
```

The obvious answer is "permissions!"  Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that's not it:

```
# ls -ld /var/www/xdebug-profiles/
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 2013-01-02 10:40 /var/www/xdebug-profiles/
```

Using Firebug, I can see that the xdebug cookies are definitely set in the browser to trigger profiling and tracing.  However, even when I disable triggered and enable global in php.ini, I still don't get any output.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm fresh out...

Comment: Does `phpinfo` show the modified ini settings?  Ubuntu's PHP versions tend to use a multitude of files, and you may have modified the wrong one.

Comment: No, phpinfo doesn't show the profiler and tracer imperative values.  Which is strange, because phpinfo DOES show the xdebug imperative values.  I installed xdebug via PECL, so I've been modifying php.ini.

Comment: Make sure you're editing the ini file mentioned in the phpinfo output.  There are ... too many.

Comment: Oh, it definitely is the correct php.ini.  That, at least, I am used to :)
I agree - all the includes that Ubuntu fiddles with make it a bit of a spaghetti code nightmare situation.

Comment: One gotcha is a php.ini setting like this: `xdebug.trace_output_name=%s.%t`.  If `%s` expands to an empty string (e.g., a script containing a `#!/bin/env php` shebang), then all the trace outputs to _hidden_ files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha.  After some playing around and seeing some odd things pop up in phpinfo(), it looks like "#" is deprecated for comments in php.ini, so the hash marks in my php.ini were blowing it up.  Replaced them with semicolons, and now all is well.  Bit tricky, that one...